# How to build a Regex in java to detect a whitespace or end of a string?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a Regex to find and extract the string containing Post office box. 
Here is two examples:

1. str = "some text  p.o. box 12456 Floor 105 streetName Street";
2. str = "po box 1011";
3. str = "post office Box 12 Floor 105 Tallapoosa Street";
4. str = "leclair ryan pc p.o. Box 2499 8th floor 951 east byrd street";
5. str = "box 1 slot 3 building 2 136 harvey road";

Here is my pattern and code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("p.*o.*box \\d+(\\z|\\s)"); 
       Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
       int count =0;
       while(m.find()) {
           count++;
           System.out.println("Match number "+count);
           System.out.println("start(): "+m.start());
           System.out.println("end(): "+m.end());
       }
```

It works with the second example and note for the first one!
If change my pattern to the following:

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("p.*o.*box \d+ ");

It works just for the first example.
The question is how to group the Regex for end of string "\z" and Regex for whitespace "\s" or " "?

New Pattern:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)((p.*o.*box\s*\w\s*\d*(\z|\s*)|(box\s*\w\s*\d*(\z|\s*)) ))");

Comment: [The code seems working](https://ideone.com/qcU6Ow).

Comment: I'd expect to see a regex like this "p.*o.*box (\d+)" if looking for the number group following "po box". And I'd expect the usage of [group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) method.

Comment: Oh, I did not point it out: Either I am missing something or you do not need to detect "whitespace or eos" if you just group digits. The first non-digit will end the group.

Comment: @Wiktor you are right it is working, the problem was case sensitivity!

Comment: So, just add `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag or pre-pend `(?i)` to the pattern.

Comment: I posted my answer with some explanations and enhancements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the [following code](https://ideone.com/4NTkqS):

```
String str = "some text p.o. box 12456 Floor 105 streetName Street";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bp\\.?\\s*o\\.?\\s*box\\s*(\\d+)(?:\\z|\\s)"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
int count =0;
while(m.find()) {
      count++;
      System.out.println("Match: "+m.group(0));
      System.out.println("Digits: "+m.group(1));
      System.out.println("Match number "+count);
      System.out.println("start(): "+m.start());
      System.out.println("end(): "+m.end());
}
```

To make the pattern case insensitive, just add `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag to the `Pattern.compile` declaration or pre-pend the inline `(?i)` modifier to the pattern.

Also, `.*` matches any characters other than a newline zero or more times, I guess you wanted to match `.` optionally. So, you need just `?` quantifier and to escape the dot so as to match a literal dot. Note how I used `(...)` to capture digits into Group 1 (it is called a *capturing group*). The group where you match the end of the string or space is inside a *non-capturing grouo* (`(?:...)`) that is used for grouping only, not for storing its value in the memory buffer. Since you wanted to match a word boundary there, I suggest replacing `(?:\\z|\\s)`  with  a mere `\\b`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bp\\.?\\s*o\\.?\\s*box\\s*(\\d+)\\b");
```

Comment: As I am applying it over a large data sets I am facing many different cases. However I improved my pattern also still not able to detect all of the cases, or I am extracting wrong part of the text.  I checked your pattern also which shows alot improvment still not detecting all of the cases. Here is some more examples plus my new pattern:  str = "post office Box 12 Floor 105 Tallapoosa Street";   str = "leclair ryan pc p.o. Box 2499  8th floor 951 east byrd street";   str = "box 1  slot 3 building 2 136 harvey road";   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(p.*o.*box\\s*\\w\\s*\\d*(\\z|\\s*))");

Comment: Sorry It is a mess in the comment, I will add the examples and pattern to the question

Comment: Try [`(?i)(?:\\bp(?:\\.|ost)?\\s*o(?:\\.|ffice)?\\s*)?box\\s*(\\d+)\\b`](https://regex101.com/r/uC5hL8/1) then.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the new strings but as the dataset is error prone, I would like not to add restriction like "ffice" or "ost".

Comment: These are not restrictions, these are *alternatives*. If you have "post office Box 456", you need to allow matching the full word.

Comment: You are right!, but what if there is a typo or new style in there? Bytheway Thank u so much!

Comment: You will have to account for that in the  pattern. Machines cannot think for us, humans.

Comment: Thank u so much indeed!

Comment: BTW, please consider accepting the answer that worked for you best.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple items in your regex that look like they need work. From what I understand you want to extract the P.O. Box number from strings of such format that you've provided. Given that, the following regex will accomplish what you want, with a following explanation. See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/cQ8lH3/2

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("p\.?o\.? box [^ \r\n\t]+");`

Firstly, you need to  use only ONE slash, for escape sequences. Also, you must escape the dots. If you do not escape the dots, regex will match `.` as ANY single character. `\.` will instead match a dot symbol.

Next, you need to change the `*` [quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) after the `\.` to a `?`. Why? The `*` symbol will match zero or more of the preceding symbol while the `?` quantifier will match only one or none.

Finally rethink how you're matching the box number. Instead of matching all characters AND THEN white space, just match everything that isn't a whitespace. `[^ \r\n\t]+` will match all characters that are NOT a space (), carriage return (`\r`), newline (`\n`), or tab (`\t`). Therefore it will consume the box number and stop as soon as it hits any whitespace or end of file.

Some of these changes may not be necessary to get your code to work for the examples you gave, but they are the proper way to build the regex you want.

Comment: can you tell me more on regex, it's been puzzling for me

Comment: Thanks @AlienHoboken!  it works now the problem was case sensitivity. Anyway I have to use two slashes otherwise I get error!